# sql join values from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

i came up by visiting **[this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24233/selecting-two-values-from-the-same-table-but-under-different-conditions)**.

so i made a query like this

```
SELECT ru.iUserId,ru.iRefUserId,CONCAT(ru.vName,ru.vLastName) AS userName,CONCAT(iru.vName,iru.vLastName) AS RefUserName
FROM `register_user` ru
 INNER JOIN `register_user` iru
 ON ru.iRefUserId = iru.iRefUserId
WHERE ru.iRefUserId > 0
```

And Database is like this
[image]
So basically my need is i need an refUserId User Full Name When i am querying like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE iRefUserId > 0
```

Above Query Result output me same name as the userName
[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. And take a look at [mcve], make it easy to assist you!

Comment: i already provided the sample data that is required for understand the concern @jarlh

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557

Comment: @jarlh ok i'll take care of this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for an outer join: Show all users along with their ref user, if such exists.

```
SELECT
  ru.iuserid,
  ru.irefuserid,
  CONCAT(ru.vname, ru.vlastname) AS username,
  CONCAT(iru.vname, iru.vlastname) AS refusername
FROM register_user ru
LEFT OUTER JOIN register_user iru ON iru.iuserid = ru.irefuserid
ORDER BY ru.iuserid;
```

I've corrected the erroneous join condition (wrong ID). Moreover, as there exists no user with user ID 0, and I guess you just meant to avoid looking that ID up, I dropped the condition `ru.iRefUserId > 0`. It is not needed, because the outer join handles this already.

Answer (score -1):

need to change join key

```
SELECT ru.iUserId,ru.iRefUserId,
CONCAT(ru.vName,ru.vLastName) AS userName,
CONCAT(iru.vName,iru.vLastName) AS RefUserName
FROM `register_user` ru
  JOIN `register_user` iru
 ON ru.iuserid = iru.iRefUserId
WHERE ru.iRefUserId > 0
```

note i have given  `WHERE ru.iRefUserId > 0` this codition becuase you given in your answer that's why but if you put this then you 1st will be ignored always

Comment: not working ..! when i run `SELECT ru.iUserId,ru.iRefUserId, CONCAT(ru.vName,ru.vLastName) AS userName FROM `register_user` ru WHERE ru.iRefUserId > 0` than i found one data but when i run your query it return 0 results

Comment: @TarangP https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0013871c7e8ad5768a411726fab1763c chcecck the link i created demo for you and its working fine before down vote please chekc 1st

Comment: i didn't do that @Zaynul